# Invalid prop: type check failed yet the code works as I was expecting

Tags: vuetify.js

Inside of a grid layout I was attempting to set two column sizes dynamically depending on a boolean flag like this `<v-col v-if="this.displayMeeting" cols="4">` and below setting the second column like this `<v-col :cols="[displayMeeting ? '8' : '12']">`

When the page displays, I get this in the console

`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "cols". Expected Boolean, String, Number, got Array`

but the page layout works.  If the meeting window is present, I get two cols one `class="col col-4"` and the other `class="col col-8"`.  If I falsy set the boolean flag the one column goes away and the second column jumps from 8 to 12.

So it works, but with two warnings in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing an array and its expecting Boolean, Number or String so replace it with String by removing the square bracket wrapping.

```
<v-col :cols="displayMeeting ? '8' : '12'">
<!--- here --^^-------------------------^^---->
```

Comment: Doh.  Weird that it still worked though.  Resolved.